# Issues with retrieving data from Access database using criteria from JTextField objects

Tags: java, database, ms-access, database-connection, ucanaccess

I have created user login window in java and i am getting some issues regarding retrieving saved data from ms access database.
Here is my code:

```
package databaseretrievedata;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Databaseretrievedata {
 Databaseretrievedata(){
     JFrame edit=new JFrame();
     edit.setBounds(300,200,550,120);
     edit.setUndecorated(false);
     edit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     JPanel p=new JPanel();
     p.setBounds(0,0,600,400);
     edit.add(p);
     JTextField field=new JTextField(20);
     field.setBounds(100,200,120,20);
     p.add(field);
     JTextField field1=new JTextField(20);
     field1.setBounds(100,300,120,20);
     p.add(field1);
     JButton b=new JButton("Click Me");
     b.setBounds(0,100,100,20);
     p.add(b);
     JRootPane pane=b.getRootPane();
     pane.setDefaultButton(b);
     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
             try {
                 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\real estate.accdb");
                 Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                 String sql="select Username,Password from table where Username='"+field+"'and Password='"+field1+"'";
                 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                 if(rs.next())
                 {
                      JFrame editframe=new JFrame();
                      editframe.setBounds(300,200,400,200);
                      editframe.setUndecorated(false);
                      editframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                      editframe.setVisible(true);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No record Found");
                 }
             } 
             catch (Exception ex) 
             {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
             }
         }
     });
     edit.setVisible(true);
 }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Databaseretrievedata v=new Databaseretrievedata();
    }

}
```

Here is the file in the database where i saved my data.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have created one text field for username and password field for getting password from the user inside JFrame and when i entered the same username and password which i saved in ms access database i got 'No record Found'although i have saved that data in the database and i want this,that when user enter username and password in the provided fields then a new JFrame opens up.
I am not pretty sure where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Divide and concur. If the problem retrieving the data from database, can you post a code that does that successful without the GUI ?  In other words post an [MCVE] focused on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Swager you are missing `getText()` method from your query 
you should write your `sql` like this `String sql = "select Username,Password from simba where Username='"+field.getText()+"'and Password='"+field1.getText()+"'";`

Answer (score 2):

Your `sql` is missing something, your statement:

```
String sql="select Username,Password from simba where Username='"+field+"'and Password='"+field1+"'";
```

This won't be what you're actually expecting here. Since the `JTextField` does not provide a special `toString()` method for its text, so that's why you can't find any matching entry in your database.

You need to retrieve the entered username, respectively the password by calling the `getText()` method on the `JTextField`:

`String sql = "select Username,Password from simba where Username='"+field.getText()+"'and Password='"+field1.getText()+"'";`

In such cases it is helpful to also print your query to the console to spot mistakes instantly

Comment: Good advice re: inspecting the `sql` string. This answer would be even better if it included the obligatory warning against using *dynamic SQL* (and recommended using a *parameterized query* via a `PreparedStatement` instead).